# Redirect Specific URL for Mobile Devices (NGINX)

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the homepage (www.example.com) to a specific mobile landing page (www.example.com/m)

I only want the redirect to happen on mobile devices, and i'm using NGINX

Any help is greatly appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The homepage can be isolated using an exact match [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) statement. Use a regular expression on the `user-agent` header to identify the conditions to redirect to `/m`.

For example:

```
location = / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ some-regular-expression) {
        return 301 /m;
    }
    rewrite ^ /index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) to create variables whose values depend on values of other variables.

For example :

```
map $http_host $name {
   hostnames;

   example.com   1;
}

map $http_user_agent $mobile {

"~*iphone"    1;

}
```

From version .0.9.6 you can use regular expression ~* means the regular expression in case insensitive and ~ means it is case sensitive.This way you can map your hostnames with user agent.

Hope this helps you out.